# Statements after recursion call

Tags: recursion

Help me understand the output of this program:

```
 int n;
 void rec() {
        n = n + 1;
        if (n < 3) {
            rec();
            System.out.println(n);  // (*)
        }
    }
```

Output is "3 3". why line (*) is even executed?

Comment: How does n even have a value?

Comment: Probably because at some point `n < 3`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming `n` is initialized to 0 at the beginning:

1. The first time the function is called `n` gets incremented to 1. 1 < 3 therefore `rec()` is called a second time.
2. The second time through `n` gets incremented to 2. 2 < 3 therefore `rec()` is called a third time.
3. Now the third time through `n` gets incremented to 3. 3 is not less than 3, therefore the `if` statement doesn't execute. So now you exit the current call of the function (third time) and return to the the previous call, which is the second call.
4. Now that the call to `rec()` has finished in your second call, `System.out.println` is called and the value of `n` (3) is displayed. Now the second call finishes, so you exit the current call of the function (second time) and return to the previous call, which is the first call.
5. Now you're in the first call of the function and since the call to `rec()` has finished, you call `System.out.println` again, which again displays the value `3`.